# set database pulled application constants on startup

Tags: servlets, constants, servlet-listeners

I have a lot of dropdown menus in my application. The contents of these dropdown menus is read from the database.

Currently, to avoid pulling these values back every-time I want to use them, I pull them back once when I first need them and store them in the session after that.

This is not good. I do want to be storing them in the session as there are a number of them, and I think it's a bit, well, clunky. I would like to ideally (assuming you don't disagree), store these 'constants' (they aren't traditional constants, but they won't change for the duration of the deployment), in the application scope, so they need only be pulled back from the database once per deployment.

What I'm wondering is, what is the way to store these dropdown values in the application context at startup?

Comment: A [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Comment: If you use spring you could use the cache abstraction: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: Caching is the best approach, especially if they are fixed across the application for each user would suggest to keep scope as application level. There are several ways of caching from using a HashMap to Coherence Cache, depends on how big your data is.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm going to go with the ServletContextListener. @SotiriosDelimanolis If you post that as an answer with a bit more detail, I'll accept it and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interface by the name of [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) which provides a hook into the initialization of your servlet context. The `ServletContext` is your application's context, ie. its configuration.

One way to do what you are describing is to implement this interface and register the `ServletContextListener` either in `web.xml` or by annotating the class with `@WebListener`.

In the `contextInitialized()` method, you would pull the constants, set them up in any way you needed to and then put them in the `ServletContext` as attributes

```
@WebListener
public static class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        int someConstant = 42;
        context.setAttribute("myConstant", someConstant);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can then access these constants anywhere you have access to the `ServletContext`.

In a `Servlet` or `Filter`, you can get it from the `ServletRequest`

```
HttpServletRequest request = ....;
request.getServletContext();
```

You also have access to it from the `init()` methods of `Servlet` and `Filter` if you want to add more attributes there.

Comment: @MasNotsram You are welcome! There's also the option of a `ServletContainerInitializer`, but I'll let you look that one up.

Comment: `ServletContainerInitializer` serves an entirely different purpose. The `ServletContextListener` is perfectly fine for the very purpose as stated in the concrete question in its current form.

Comment: @BalusC You wouldn't recommend using the `ServletContainerInitializer` to add servlet context attributes parallel to doing container initialization?